# Get data from webpage

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to resolve ip. I make jquery ajax get, to get data from url, but in console, there is - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

```
$.get("http://tools.whois.net/whoisbyip/", function (response) {
console.log(response);
}, "jsonp");
```

I have working code:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
}, "jsonp");
```

but i don't get all information, that i need in this.

Comment: are you sure that the http://tools.whois.net/whoisbyip/ url is set to deliver a json file? Looks like instead of json it's recieving something else. hence the "<"

Comment: Jup, maybe. Maybe someone know some good ip resolve sites, that return json ?

Comment: http://ip-api.com/json I've used this site, it has slightly more info. I am sure you can find what you need with a quick google search.

Comment: Nope, this desn't return what i need :(

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
$.get("http://ip-api.com/json", function (response) {
console.log(response);
}, "json");
```

I changed "jsonp" for "json" :).

Your first URL "tools.whois.net/whoisbyip/" response with an error and your other URL "ipinfo.io" don't return nothing.

Example: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ (at the end of the website)

Comment: This is working, but i don't get information, what i need. I need real company name, but here i get just internet provider name.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what is exactly you need :S

Comment: http://private.dnsstuff.com/tools/whois.ch?ip=68.179.6.226

There is name - LONG DIVISION. I need it. But this site have some Origins, so i can't get json if i have my site on other server.

Comment: Ok, I understand but sorry so much, I can't help you :S.